# Consulta em duas tabelas diferentes no Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress

Estou com um código, onde ele me retorna alguns dados de todos os usuários da tabela `wp_usermeta`, ( no caso estou puxando apenas o Nome completo, e as `Capabilities`, porém para ficar mais completa minha tabela, gostaria de adicionar o email dos usuários, que está na tabela `wp_users` , como eu posso fazer uma `query` que pegue os valores de ambos as tabelas?
Segue código:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$sql = "
  SELECT user_id,meta_key,meta_value
  FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} 
  WHERE ({$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'first_name' OR {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'last_name' OR {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities')";
$ansatte = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

$users = array();
foreach ($ansatte as $a) {
  $users[$a->user_id][$a->meta_key] = $a->meta_value;
}

foreach ($users as $u) {
    echo $u['first_name'].' '.$u['last_name'].' '.$u['wp_capabilities'].'<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa fazer uma consulta via SQL diretamente pra isso. Pode usar [`get_users`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) pra pegar uma lista, e [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) se quiser um usuário específico.

Ambas retornam objetos [`WP_User`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/) que tem todas as informações que você está buscando.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer um join entre as tabelas:

Esta query retorna a coluna que você deseja:

```
SELECT um.user_id, um.meta_key, um.meta_value, u.user_email
FROM wp_usermeta um 
       inner join wp_users u
          on u.ID = um.user_id
  WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' 
     OR meta_key = 'last_name' 
     OR meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
```